# Firefox 13 PC and jagged Fonts

Tags: firefox, fonts, rendering, cleartype

On Firefox PC, The font is jagged.

Question:
Is there a current CSS workaround or accepted solution to this Firefox PC problem?

I used fontsquirrel to transform my desktop TTF font into EOT, WOFF, and etc.
The only browser that is giving me problems is Firefox PC. All other browsers/os combinations look smooth. Does cleartype have something to do with this?

Comment: It might.  Are you on windows vista or 7?  If so, open the control panel.  search for "cleartype."  You should get the "Cleartype Tuner" or "Adjust Cleartype Text" or something.  Run its configuration wizard and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: thanks. Is there no CSS fix for Firefox PC as there exists for IE?
For IE, I'm using an IE-specific filter to force Window's ClearType to turn off. Fixes the jagged font issue on IE.

body { 
letter-spacing: 0; 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=hIEfix.png,sizingMethod=crop); 
zoom:1; 
}

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.  I only commented because I have also seen a few applications have issues if cleartype settings were improperly set and thought you might have been onto something.  Can you try disabling it and reenabling it?

Comment: @Wug - that will fix the problem on he's computer, what about the users of the site?